# Detect how a unit test was triggered

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

We have an environment that has a very long running unit test. The method for this unit test is called "RunDataTest" which is populated using `DynamicData`. The `DynamicData` comes from a method `GetUnitTestConfig` that reads the configuration for each individual unit test from a network drive.

On the server/build agent I want to run all unit tests.

But on my local machine I want to see a *list of these unit tests* in my Test Explorer, but I **don't** want to start them when I press "Run All Unit Tests": I want to start them individually when explicitly clicking on the unit test and start only the selected unit test. This means I want to detect who/how the unit tests was triggered or better which Visual Studio function triggered the unit test.

My problem is that I'm lacking an indicator to find **out how the unit test was triggered**. Is there any property to find this out?

Comment: *I don't want to start them when I press "Run All Unit Tests"* - Seems to me that the solution is just to not press "Run All Unit Tests". Why would you expect "Run All" to do anything else but **run all**? If I click on *Run All*, I would expect it to run all, the same as when I press *Reduce volume* on my media player, I would expect the volume to go lower.

Comment: @KenWhite. You are somehow right, but if tests are [Ignored] they also do not run. Ignoring tests would also work, but I need a way to selectively turn them on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are asking how to detect when a unit test is triggered, the real problem is that these long-running tests are being triggered locally where you would like to run only fast tests. There are a couple of solutions to this problem that mostly boil down to filtering tests in Visual Studio Test Explorer.

1. Put all of your fast-running tests in a single folder. Filter by full name in Visual Studio Test Explorer: `fullname:ProjectNamespace.Folder`
2. Categorize tests using the `[TestCategory(string)]` attribute as either fast or slow:

   ```cs
   [TestMethod]
   [TestCategory("fast")]
   public void ReallyFastUnitTest() { ... }

   [TestMethod]
   [TestCategory("slow")]
   public void TestThatLoadsDataFromNetworkDrive() { ... }
   ```

   Then filter by category in Visual Studio Test Explorer: `trait:fast`

More info about filtering tests in Test Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022#group-and-filter-the-test-list